# How to assign key to push button on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, button, push

I have a gui which works fine when i click on them but instead of clicking i want to activate them by just pressing a key (like uparrow) on keyboard.I did create a keypressfnc on first button (C3). but i don't know what to do now.Here is my gui code

```
function varargout = untitled(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @untitled_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @untitled_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before untitled is made visible.
function untitled_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

handles.output = hObject;


guidata(hObject, handles);




function varargout = untitled_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
sr = 16000;
T = 4; %  seconds duration
t = 0:(1/sr):T; 
n = 20;
f = ((2^(1/12))^(n-49))*440;
a = linspace(0,1,numel(t));
y = exp(-a*4).*sin(2*pi*f*t);
sound(y, sr);
plot(t, y);


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
sr = 16000;
T = 4; %  seconds duration
t = 0:(1/sr):T; 
n = 40;
f = ((2^(1/12))^(n-49))*440;
a = linspace(0,1,numel(t));
y = exp(-a*4).*sin(2*pi*f*t);
sound(y, sr);
plot(t, y);

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton4.
function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton5.
function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton5 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton6.
function pushbutton6_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton6 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton7.
function pushbutton7_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton7 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on key press with focus on pushbutton1 and none of its controls


% --- Executes on key press with focus on pushbutton1 and none of its controls.


% --- Executes on key press with focus on pushbutton1 and none of its controls.
function pushbutton1_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  structure with the following fields (see UICONTROL)
%   Key: name of the key that was pressed, in lower case
%   Character: character interpretation of the key(s) that was pressed
%   Modifier: name(s) of the modifier key(s) (i.e., control, shift) pressed
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyPressFcn` that is called is going to be the one that belongs to the object in focus when the key is pressed.  This is probably going to be the last object that was clicked on.  Here you set the `KeyPressFcn` as a property of the pushbutton but this will only be called when the pushbutton is the object in focus.  This includes the figure window as well.  This example shows how to implement a key press event for both a button and a figure, where the `KeyPressFcn` value in both is set to the same function.

```
function KeyPressExample

fig = figure();
set(fig, 'KeyPressFcn', @ChangeColorKeyPress, 'Tag', 'MainGUI');

button = uicontrol(fig, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [.4 .4 .2 .2], ...
    'String', 'Change Color', ...
    'CallBack', @ChangeColorButtonPress, ...
    'KeyPressFcn', @ChangeColorKeyPress);

    function ChangeColorButtonPress(hobj, EventData, handles)

        set(findobj('Tag', 'MainGUI'), 'Color', rand(3, 1));

    end

    function ChangeColorKeyPress(hobj, EventData, handles)

        if strcmp(EventData.Key, 'uparrow')

            set(findobj('Tag', 'MainGUI'), 'Color', rand(3,1));

        end

    end

end
```

Comment: I am a  very beginner matlab student.I just want my function to run when i click uparrow.i could not understand your example sorry.I have no ( button = uicontrol() ) for example

Comment: The example I gave is a programmatic GUI that uses the KeyPressFcn property to execute a function.  The figure background will change color when you press the up arrow.  To do the same in GUIDE you have to add a KeyPressFcn to any object that could be in focus at a time you want the KeyPressFcn to execute.  This basically means adding it to every object in your GUI including to the figure window itself.  Right now you have it added to just your pushbutton so the KeyPressFcn will only execute if you hit the up arrow key after clicking on your pushbutton.

Comment: So it is much harder to do it in GUIDE.it is easier to do in programmatic way.I changed your code a bit now  and my function works now

Comment: Glad you got it working. To be honest GUIDE has no purpose past some initial layout help. 'Development' is actually harder since changing things and linking functions is so much more complicated than with a programmatic GUI. But that is mostly personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine the key press and click callbacks into a single callback using a try/catch statement:

```
function KeyPressExample

fig = figure();
set(fig, 'KeyPressFcn', @ChangeColorButtonPress,'Tag', 'MainGUI');

button = uicontrol(fig, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [.4 .4 .2 .2], ...
'String', 'Change Color', ...
'CallBack', @ChangeColorButtonPress, ...
'KeyPressFcn', @ChangeColorButtonPress);

function ChangeColorButtonPress(varargin)
    EventData=varargin{2}
    try
        if strcmp(EventData.Key, 'uparrow')
        set(findobj('Tag', 'MainGUI'), 'Color', rand(3,1));
        end
    catch
        set(findobj('Tag', 'MainGUI'), 'Color', rand(3, 1));
    end    
end
end
```